# Angular js app can't generate right page through facebook sharing using prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, nginx, amazon-s3, single-page-application, prerender

I have developed single page app using angularjs. Angularjs source is stored on amazon s3.
For SEO and social sharing, i have used prerender.io. My webserver is nginx containing amazon S3. I think my nginx.conf is configured well. But, when trying to share on facebook, wrong result appears because binded model in angular is not replaced dynamically. I checked page-caching is succeeded on http://prerender.io, but facebook-shared result appeared as if binded model is not replaced.
I wonder why not. Help me plz!! My nginx's setting follows.

> http{
>
> ```
> # configuration of the web application server
> server {
>     ......
> }
>
> server {
>     listen      80;
>     server_name example.com;
>     root        /;
>
>     location / {
>         try_files $uri @prerender;
>     }
>
>     location @prerender {
>         proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token lololololololololol;
>
>         set $prerender 0;        
>         if($http_user_agent ~* 
>          "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora >               link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot") {
>             set $prerender 1;
>         }
>         if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
>             set $prerender 1;
>         }
>         if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
>             set $prerender 0;
>         }
>         if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3
>                        |rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4
>                        |m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent)")
>         {
>             set $prerender 0;
>         }
>
>         #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
>         resolver 8.8.8.8;
>
>
>         if ($prerender = 1) {
>
>             #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
>             set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
>             rewrite .* /$scheme://example.s3-website-ap-
>                     northeast1.amazonaws.com$request_uri? break;
>             proxy_pass http://$prerender;
>         }
>         if ($prerender = 0) {
>             proxy_pass $scheme://example.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com;
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Send me a URL at todd@prerender.io and I'll be happy to look into it for you!

Comment: @Prerender.io I sended mail to u. Thanks for ur help :)